# Why won't my Rails function abort?

Tags: debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to debug an application that someone else wrote. In my `production.log`, I see:

```
  Processing by Friendster::AppsController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {SOMESTUFF}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
```

So I go to the `app/controller/friendster/apps_controllers` and look at the `home` function and it is:

```
  def home
    show_app_container
  end
```

So I changed it to:

```
  def home
    puts "container"
    abort "SHAMOON"

    show_app_container
  end
```

Just so I can see some sort of error or log.  But nothing shows up anywhere. Nothing renders differently. I don't know if there's caching going on or if I'm in the right function. Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

I also ran a `bundle exec rake routes` and got:

```
friendster_app_home POST   /publishers/:publisher_id/apps/:app_id/home(.:format)                             {:action=>"home", :controller=>"friendster/apps"}
                    GET    /publishers/:publisher_id/apps/:app_id/home(.:format)                             {:action=>"home", :controller=>"friendster/apps"}
```

Although there are quite a few routes with `GET    /publishers/:publisher_id/apps/:app_id/home(.:format)`, so I'm not sure what that means. This is the only `friendster` one.

**EDIT: Adding Base controller parent**

```
class Friendster::BaseController < AppsController
  protected

end
```

Comment: Do you have a `before_filter` or `around_filter` applied by either this controller or any of its parents? It seems possible that something is failing before your "home" action is invoked. You should also see some output in the browser, including a stack-trace. If not, you're probably running your app in its production environment instead of development. Try switch to the development environment.

Comment: I commented out the `before_filter` and `around_filter` of my controller. It does have a parent: `class Friendster::AppsController < Friendster::BaseController`, so I to that and it's empty. Posted in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Include the [pry gem](http://pryrepl.org/), call `binding.pry` inside of `#home` and Pry will spawn an interactive debugger in the console.

```
def home   
  binding.pry
  show_app_container
end
```